# Media player get stuck in the middle of a buffered range on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

### WHAT IS MY PROBLEM?

My website's live streaming player use hls.js. From my server's stat, there is many case where player get stuck in the middle of a buffered range.

Here is my server raw stat log(removed some useless params):

```
tm=2019-09-27 12:04:41`bufferLevel=8.447303999999974`currentTime=158.4`buffered=[6.024,166.832]`readyState=4`ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36 QBCore/3.53.1153.400 QQBrowser/9.0.2524.400 Tencent AppMarket/4.8 GameCenter
```

`currentTime` is got by `HTMLMediaElement.currentTime` and buffered is got by `HTMLMediaElement.buffered`:

```
currentTime=158.4
buffered=[6.024,166.832]
readyState=4
```

From W3c:

> If HTMLMediaElement.buffered contains a TimeRange that includes the current playback position and enough data to ensure uninterrupted playback:
>
> 1. Set the HTMLMediaElement.readyState attribute to HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA.
> 2. Playback may resume at this point if it was previously suspended by a transition to HAVE_CURRENT_DATA.

In this case, `613.3` is in the middle of `[469.277,677.612]`, video should be progressing, but it is not.

Hls.js will periodly check `currentTime` has progressed every 100ms. if `currentTime` has not progressed for 1000ms, then hls.js will trigger `STALL` event and I will send a stall stat to server.

I cannot reproduce this problem on my side, it only appears on my server stat.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

shaka player has a module detect this case(https://www.ellealcatrase.eu/player2/docs/api/lib_media_stall_detector.js.html), Its comment shows that:

> Some platforms/browsers can get stuck in the middle of a
>   buffered range (e.g. when seeking in a background tab). Detect when
>   we get stuck so that the player can respond.

but I cannot reproduce when my browser is in a background tab.